# Unable to use any new plugins on my Ionic 3 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have a project, that was built on Ionic version  3. I have not updated my CLI to Ionic 4, as it is not necessary to me . Now after I install any plugin it says, greater version of the ionic-core or angular-core required. Ex: If I run

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture
npm install @ionic-native/media-capture
```

I get a warning like

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/media@5.3.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install
```

If I try to update ionic-core some other plugins will throw warning saying they need older version of the ionic-core.
Also there is some changes on the import statement where ngx is used

```
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
```

But when I try to use the plugin with below code

```
   let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 }
this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
  .then(
    (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(data),
    (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
  );
```

**I will get error like uncaught type error object(…)** is not a function. This is been common for most of the plugins, I’m not able to use any plugin from few days. Please help me by saying, what is the mistake that I’m doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade the version of your new plugin, you just need to know what version is enabled on ionic 3 , you can try something like this :

`npm install @ionic-native/media-capture@3.0.0`

Comment: Hi, I tried it. Installed the plugin via this command "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture" and later did "npm install @ionic-native/media-capture@3.0.0", but still the same warnings. npm WARN @ionic-native/media@5.3.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/media@5.3.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Did you tried to downgrade media plugin ? (not media capture)

Comment: No, I did not try it. You want me to execute this ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media@3.0.0 and npm install @ionic-native/media-capture@3.0.0

Comment: Yes something like that `npm install @ionic-native/media@3.0.0`

Comment: Can you give the config.xml file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190427/discussion-between-sam-and-vasanth).